# Issue with the number format in twig with negative numbers

Tags: twig

`{{ 9800.333|number_format(2) }}` is displayed as `9,800.33`

But with negative numbers `{{ -9800.333|number_format(2) }}` it displays `-9`

So is there any way to get it displayed as `-9,800.33`?

Comment: Very odd problem but can be fixed with by adding parantheses to force twig to treat the string as a whole `{{ (-9800.333)|number_format(2) }}`

Comment: Thanks issue is resolved :)

Comment: Was added to the [twig documentation](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I noticed if you put the negative number in a `set` statement it will also work:

```
{{ 9800.333|number_format(2) }}

{% set number = -9800.333 %}
{{ number|number_format(2) }}
```

See the working twigfiddle here: https://twigfiddle.com/3rfw66

So maybe if you are writing more complex piece of code, you could use that. @DarkBee 's solution works as well.